# Applying a package

Tags: packages

I have downloaded a template which includes a `\usepackage{tamuconfig}` command.  I have the `tamuconfig.sty` downloaded, but I do not know how to make it apply to the template.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Put the `tamuconfig.sty` in the same folder as `your-filename.tex`

Comment: You may want to take a look at: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files If you follow @texenthusiast's suggestion, then `tamuconfig.sty` will only be available to that particular `.tex` file, but there is a way to make it available for all `.tex` files, explained in the linked question and answers. Also, welcome to TeX.SX!